# Mask SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, mask, skspritenode, skcropnode

I add few nodes to my sks file, and now I want to add some mask to the most lowest node `SKSpriteNode`. Structure is as shown below:

[image]

where

- green - wordInfoHolder
- red - container for Label
- whiteText - label

Now I want to hide part that is shown in red. To perform such action I read that `SKCropNode` can be used.

I able to find all my nodes in scene file and save them to variables.

```
if let holder = childNode(withName: "wordInfoHolder") as? SKSpriteNode {
        wordInfoHolder = holder
        if let wordSwitchNode = wordInfoHolder?.childNode(withName:"wordSwitchNode") as? SKSpriteNode {
            self.wordSwitchNode = wordSwitchNode

            if let label = self.wordSwitchNode?.childNode(withName:"infoLabel") as? SKLabelNode {
                wordSwitchLabelNode = label
            }
       }
}
```

all 3 objects are stored and correct.

Now I want to add some mask to root object.

For such purpose I prepared mask image:

[image]

and try to do something like:

```
  guard let holder = wordInfoHolder else { return }
  let positionToSet = holder.position
  let mask = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rectangle_mask")
  let cropNode = SKCropNode()
  holder.removeFromParent()
  cropNode.addChild(holder)
  cropNode.maskNode = mask
  cropNode.position = positionToSet
  self.addChild(cropNode)
```

But I see nothing. I expect to see green part of `SKSpriteNode`.

What was done wrong?

Comment: holder doesn't appear to be used outside of your assigning variables. Shouldn't it be cropNode.addChild(wordInfoHolder) ?

Comment: my fail - `holder` from `if let holder = wordInfoHolder`, add update to listing

Comment: does it fix the issue?

Comment: i wish, but no, it's just clarification that `holder` is same obj as `wordInfoHolder`

Comment: that should never happen, unless you are running the cropNode code inside of that if statement

Comment: this is just copy-past code issue (I copied not all code from xCode to so, so some unwrap part was missed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have set zPosition on all your objects.

I'm quite sure the issue is that because you are moving your holder object from the scene to the cropNode it is retaining it's position info from the scene (for example if it's position in the scene was 500, 500 it's position in the cropNode is now 500, 500)

I was able to recreate your issue and by setting the holder.position to zero the issue went away.

In the picture below I am using the yellow box as mask and the blue and pink boxes are test objects to ensure the the cropNode is placed between them.

[image]

```
if let holder = self.childNode(withName: "holder") as? SKSpriteNode {
    self.holder = holder

    if let switcher = holder.childNode(withName: "//switcher") as? SKSpriteNode {
        self.switcher = switcher
    }
}

if let mask = self.childNode(withName: "mask") as? SKSpriteNode {

    mask.removeFromParent()

    let positionToSet = holder.position
    holder.position = CGPoint.zero
    mask.position = CGPoint.zero

    let cropNode = SKCropNode()
    holder.removeFromParent()
    cropNode.addChild(holder)
    cropNode.maskNode = mask
    cropNode.position = positionToSet
    cropNode.zPosition = 10
    self.addChild(cropNode)
}
```

added tidbit

```
holder.move(toParent: cropNode)
```

can be used in place of

```
holder.removeFromParent()
cropNode.addChild(holder)
```

Comment: ah, this moment when u realize that forgot to add 1 line... Thanks! now everything works as expected